# React and react-google-login function

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

how to solve this error : {error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}
details
:
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error
:
"idpiframe_initialization_failed"

the code used :

<GoogleLogin
clientId="310251802637-c7o493rfifnh5.apps.googleusercontent.com"

```
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                  className="w-full text-white font-bold bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
                >
                  {" "}
                  Connect with Google
                </button>
              )}
              onSuccess={googleSuccess}
              onFailure={googleFailure}
              cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            ></GoogleLogin>
```